# Sort formatted date column using DataTable in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, date, datatable, iso8601

How do I sort a DataTable by human readable date?

A common problem is the formatted date you want to have users see does not sort correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assume the first column is a sortable ISO date, and the second column a human-readable, formatted date:

```
  %table.structures-list.stripe
    %thead
      %tr
        -# The ISO date column is for sorting
        %th Sortable
        %th Created
        %th Structure
        %th Area
    %tbody
      - items.each do |item|
        %tr.item{ id: dom_id(item.id) }
          -# The ISO date column is for sorting
          %td= item.created_at.iso8601
          %td= item.created_at.strftime("%d-%b-%Y")
          %td.ranked-name
            %a= link_to item.name, [item.preplan, item]
          %td= presenter.area
```

[image]

You can initialize the DataTable as follows in your (haml) view file:

```
:javascript
  $('.structures-list').DataTable({
    "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
    "pageLength": 25,
    // Have the created at column sorted by the ISO version
    "columnDefs": [
          { "targets": [1],
            "visible": true,
            "orderData": [0]
          },
          { "targets": [0],
            "visible": false
          }
    ]
  });
```

This will sort by the first column when you click the sort arrows on the second column, and hide the first column.

[image]

(This was for my future self.)

Comment: Nice.  You can also try the [Datatables moment.js sorting plugin](https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18).